# Creating public synonym at system level

Tags: sql, oracle, view, public, synonym

I have created public synonym as suggested in my other question about creating view at system level. Having said that I have created individual public synonym out of the view so that I don't have to connect to the individual domain anymore. My problem now is how to create a master kind of public synonym to capture all those synonyms which I have created earlier. To what extent the "for" statement can be used?

Example:
At system level, I will run query for each domain where MYVIEW is created :
Create or replace public synonym domain1_myview for domain1.myview;
Create or replace public synonym domain2_myview for domain2.myview;
Create or replace public synonym domain3_myview for domain3.myview;

Then I have 3 public synonym above.

Then I tried writing statement (out of desperation - not as expert) like below hoping to have just ONE Master_MYVIEW but failed:
Create or replace public synonym MASTER_MYVIEW for (select * from domain1_myview union all select * from domain2_myview union all select * from domain3_myview);

The error with the above : "ORA-00995: missing or invalid synonym identifier"

Hope someone can assist me on this task. Have a nice :) day.

Comment: I have also tried :
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM MASTER_MYVIEW for (select * from domain1.myview union all select * from domain2.myview) and so on.

But I got error : "insufficient privilege".

Common guys, help me out here. Appreciate any response.

Comment: Hi guys...
I am still waiting for intelligence response from any of you out there... really desperate here. I am out of option and I also need to know if it is possible or not to create a master synonym out of the synonym that I have mentioned earlier. Can it be other than PUBLIC owner and PUBLIC SYNONYM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a view called MASTER_MYVIEW first (you may need to deal with privileges there as well):

```
create view master_myview as select ...;
```

Then create a public synonym for that new view:

```
create or replace public synonym master_myview for <owner>.master_myview;
```

Comment: The restriction with insufficient previlege is due to my grant.

GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO admin (eg admin is the user)